# Accessing response from Google Calendar API FreebusyRequest

Tags: arrays, json, google-calendar-api

I'm making a FreebusyRequest to the Google Calendar API and am getting this back as the response (just the top part for succinctness). I can access elements like [timeMax] easily with code like:

```
$timeMax = $query->gettimeMax();
```

However, I'm unable to figure out how to access the [busy] array or the elements underneath. I don't know whether it's because those are protected, or if I'm just completely doing this wrong.

```
[calendarsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyCalendar
[calendarsDataType:protected] => map
[groupsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyGroup
[groupsDataType:protected] => map
[kind] => calendar#freeBusy
[timeMax] => 2015-10-30T10:00:00.000Z
[timeMin] => 2015-10-20T00:00:00.000Z
[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
        [calendars] => Array
            (
                [calendarname@gmail.com] => Array
                    (
                        [busy] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [start] => 2015-10-23T15:30:00-07:00
                                        [end] => 2015-10-23T16:30:00-07:00
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [start] => 2015-10-24T16:00:00-07:00
                                        [end] => 2015-10-24T20:00:00-07:00
                                    )
```

I've also tried to do a json_decode() with TRUE to make it into an associative array, but that comes up with an empty array.

Can anybody help me to access the busy info into variables? Since I can get the JSON response, it's not so much that I'm trying to figure out how to use the Google Calendar API class functions, but my question is really how can I traverse this particular JSON response to get at the [busy] element(s) using PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: I can also do something like: $calendars = $query->getCalendars(); which will get me down a couple levels, but I still can't figure out how to get down to the busy level.

Comment: You can check this link https://code.google.com/r/wwwjackychenmzb-calendar/source/browse/src/com/google/samples/meetingscheduler/util/FreeBusyTimesRetriever.java?r=12be7461578f707574f5c1c31c52c8ce128828a6 it has information about how to retrieve busy times from google calendar. Also, check this link https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/FreeBusyRequest.html for class reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked at those links before, but unfortunately couldn't understand as I don't know Java, and couldn't figure out how to mentally translate it into something using PHP. I should probably rephrase my question to ask: how can I traverse this particular JSON response to get at the busy elements?